# When attacking bases, how much loot can I get?

Tags: clash-of-clans

My question has numerous parts to it so bear with me:

1. What is the maximum amount of loot I can get from one raid?
2. What is the maximum amount of loot I can get from one building (storage/collector/clan castle/etc.)?
3. Should collectors be prioritized when attacking for loot? Or should storages?
4. What troops should I use to get either storages or collectors?

I'd like to know about these questions for all the resources (gold/elixir/dark elixir), thanks.

Comment: There's probably too many questions here, some of which I believe have already been asked and answered on here. For instance, the explanation on the maximum amount of loot available for raiding is already a fairly lengthy one. Questions 3 and 4 will depend on how much they appear to be storing (you can get an idea from their graphical representations) and where they are positioned in the base you are attacking.

Comment: As of last known mechanics, you can refer to [this wikipage](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Raids#Loot) for the lootable resources. As for no.s 3 & 4, well that's too broad as any kind of troops can be used depending on the situation. One might even be inclined just to say goblins because they do double damage to resource buildings.

Comment: As for collectors or storages, it depends on the circumstance. If there doesn't seem to be much loot in the storage, attack the collector, or vice versa. You can tell how much is in each by looking at the level of coins in each.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of: [What determines how much of my resources are available for an opponent to steal?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/153071/4797)

Answer (score -1):

This will answer your loot question: http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:113921

3 and 4: Use goblins and prioritize storage. Hope this helps :)

The percentage of gold/elixir that can be stolen from storages is 20% and is capped at 198k. This means that if more than 992k is being held in storages, it is subject to the cap.

The percentage of gold/elixir that can be stolen from mines/collectors is 50% and is capped only by the storage capacity of the mine/collector.

There is an additional 1k of each resource that can be stolen inside the Town Hall.

Therefore, calculated loot = (20% x stored resources, up to 198k) + (50% x amount in mines/collectors) + 1k.

This means that the maximum calculated loot, for each resource, that can be stolen from 1 opponent (with maxed mines/collectors and full storages) is: 198k + (7 x 75k) + 1k= 724k.

These figures are BEFORE the multiplier is applied. The multiplier is what is behind the loot "penalty" and the loot "bonus". The amount of AVAILABLE loot= calculated loot x multiplier. The multiplier is determined as follows:

```
5% for attacking someine with a TH 4+ levels lower than the attackers.
25% for attacking someone with a TH 3 levels lower than the attackers.
50% for attacking someone with a TH 2 levels lower than the attackers.
90% for attacking someone with a TH 1 level lower than the attackers.
100% for attacking someone with a TH level equivalent to the attackers.
110% for attacking someone with a TH 1 level higher than the attackers.
150% for attacking someone with a TH 2 levels higher than the attackers.
200% for attacking someone with a TH 3+ levels higher than the attackers.
```

Maximum loot after the multiplier is applied is [(200%) x (198k + 7 x 75k)]+1k = 1.447 million of either gold or elixir. This is, of course, highly unlikely for someone to actually raid.

The comprehensive formula for finding available loot is:
(multiplier percentage) x [(20% x storage amount, capped at 198k) +(50% x mine/collector amount) + 1k]=loot
NOTE: The 1k that the TH stores is subject to the PENALTY, but not the BONUS, as 1k is the most it can ever store.
In addition to what is won in battle, there are loot bonuses for being in trophy leagues. Detailed information on that can be found here: http://forum.supercell.net/showthrea...w-Leagues-work

Dark Elixir Loot:
Dark elixir storages have 5% available for raiding and dark elixir drills have 75% available for raiding. The cap for raiding from the storage is 2k, while the drills are raidable according to (75% of uncollected DE) x (loot multiplier) or the maximum capacity of the drill, whichever is lower.
The maximum amount of DE that can be looted from a single raid is: (200% x 2k)+(3 x 1.6k)=8.8k
The formula for dark elixir loot is:
(multiplier percentage) x [(5% x storage amount) + (75% x amount in drill(s))]= loot

Comment: Can you quote the relevant parts from the link in the off chance the site is down or otherwise unavailable?

Comment: Many of the figures in this post are outdated. Please verify the date of posts before posting them and this, as opposed to the wikipage I linked in my comment to the OP is not maintained by anyone.

Comment: 'Prioritise storage' is not totally correct. Attacking an empty storage will not bring a single loot gain.

Comment: Goblins aren't always the best troops to use when raiding. While they certainly rip through collectors and storages (other than the clan castle), they are extremely susceptable to mortar and mage towers. And since they prioritize resource buildings and are very fast, they are also likely to separate from the rest of your forces and be attacked by towers residing in the back of the base. So, the correct answer for what troops to use is "it depends on the base you're attacking."